# VBA: Identify Last row of formulas (or data) in sheet, copy that row, and then paste one row right below it

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to identify the last row of formulas on the sheet titled "Term Loans".  I'd then like to copy all those formulas and paste them one row below.  For example, if the last row with formulas is row 15, I'd like to copy row 15 and paste formulas into row 16.  In my code below, I get an error on the line `Worksheets("Term Loans").Range(Worksheets("Term Loans").Cells(lRow, 1)).EntireRow.Copy`  .Any advice on how to fix this would be much appreciated. The error is "Application-defined or object defined error"

```
Dim lRow As Long

Sheets("Term Loans").Select

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


        ' Now Copy the range:
        Worksheets("Term Loans").Range(Worksheets("Term Loans").Cells(lRow, 1)).EntireRow.Copy
        ' And paste to first empty row
        Worksheets("Term Loans").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: `Range(lRow)` is something like `Range(4)` which if you look up any reference or Excel help you will see is not valid syntax.

Comment: Oh I see. Do you know how I could write code to convert that 4 into a column number?

Comment: replace `Worksheets("Term Loans").Range(lRow).Copy` with `Worksheets("Term Loans").Range(Worksheets("Term Loans").Cells(lRow,1)).EntireRow.Copy` ... note that 1. I don't think your syntax on pastespecial parameters is right either; you may want to look that up, and 2. in my experience It's better not to use copy and paste; you'd typically prefer to simply set the destination row equal to the source row.

Comment: @AlexM I replaced it with the following and still received an error `Worksheets("Term Loans").Range(Worksheets("Term Loans")).Cells(lRow, 1).EntireRow.Copy`  Your's was missing a parenthesis near Worksheets but I may have put it the close parentheses in the wrong place

Comment: @AlexM please see the update to my original paste.  I'm getting an object defined error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to reference `lrow` as a range after declaring it as a `Long` and that's where the error is coming from. Try this instead, I declared some other variables in order to make the code more simple. Hope this helps:

```
Sub copypaste1rowdown()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ws.Range("A3:Q3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Dim lCol As Long
    lCol = ws.Range("A3:Q3").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To lCol
        Cells(lRow + 2, i).Copy
        Cells(lRow + 2, i).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen good catch, I meant to take it out of there. Thanks! Edited

Comment: @Miles Fett I used your code and it just coppied Cell A1 and pasted into a cell below it.  Did you mean to change the syntax to something other than A1.  Row 2 is blank if that helps.  The table starts in row 3

Comment: If you change it to `lRow = ws.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` as in the code now, as i just edited, does that work? of course `currentRegion` will give you the wrong `lRow ` if there are blanks within your range.

Comment: Edit I really appreciate your help.  It doesnt appear to be working.  It ends up showing the dotted box around cell A7 even the the table ends on row 9

Comment: I edited again, because your table starts in Row 3, you can change the cell you copy by adding 2 to the last row before copying and pasting `Range("A" & lRow + 2).Copy
    Range("A" & lRow + 2).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`

Comment: thank you your edit works for column A.  How can I most efficiently apply this to columns A through Q?

Comment: Never mind, I just copied and pasted the code over and over for every column.  Thanks!

Comment: I edited again for efficiency with the `For Next`. Glad I could help, thanks for the upvote

Comment: any idea how to set the value in column C of the new row equal to a number I've declared under the variable `strName`?  I've tried using the following code `Set Range("C" & lRow + 2).Offset(1, 0) = strName` but I receive error Object Required

Comment: Try this `Cells(lRow + 2, "C").Offset(1, 0).Value = strName`, you want to change the value of the cell, you can't pass a variable as both a string and a range.

Answer (score 2):

You error is caused by

```
Worksheets("Term Loans").Range(Worksheets("Term Loans").Cells(lRow, 1))
```

When you pass a single parameter to `Range(...)` it is interpreted as a address string.  When that parameter is a range itself, (`Worksheets("Term Loans").Cells(lRow, 1)` in this case) the *value* of that range is passed to `Range` (so `... .Cells(lRow, 1).Value` is this case)

So, unless `... .Cells(lRow, 1).Value` returns a valid address in A1 style (or the name of a Named Range), you will get an error.

Here's how to correctly reference the range

```
Sub Demo
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Term Loans")

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Now Copy the range:
    ws.Cells(lRow, 1).EntireRow.Copy
    ' And paste to first empty row
    ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

And an improved version

```
Sub Demo2
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng as Range 

    Set wb = Thisworkbook 'or Activeworkbook, or some other book you specify
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Term Loans")
    With ws
        'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
        Set rng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).EntireRow
    End With 

    ' Now Copy the range:
    rng.Copy
    ' And paste to first empty row
    rng.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' To set a specific cell in the new row to a value
    Dim MyVal as Long
    MyVal = 42
    rng.Offset(1, 0).Cells(1, 3) = MyVal
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Chris this is an excellent answer!  Do you have any idea how to make the value in column C of the new row that was just pasted equal to a value that I've declred as Long called `strName`?  I tried using `Set Range("C" & lRow + 2).Offset(1, 0) = strName` but I'm getting an Object error

Comment: Just drop the `Set`.  That is used with Objects, and a Long is not an Object.  And FWIW, why delcare as Long and use a name prefixed with `str`?

Comment: Thank you that worked. I'm not sure, I'm fairly new to VBA so some of my code is likely not best practices yet